# Best way to share beta

Tags: swift, xcode, testflight

I'm just trying to load my first app up to App Connect in order to let a few friends test it. So they can download it.
Got though the first few headaches like Frameworks not being set up correctly...

Now of course the final authorisation has failed due to lack of certain images and icons non of which I'm bothered to do right now I just want to be able to remotely share the app.

Do I really have to get all that stuff fixed first?
Is it not possible to share a slightly rough version via TestFlight?

EDIT:
These are my errors. Not sure what the first error means but the others obviously for missing image data.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd recommend fixing those errors anyway. They're simple. Just add an app icon with the correct sizes. It doesn't have to be a good/final icon yet. You can use my script here: https://gist.github.com/DaveWoodCom/0b9dd0efb9d10f0f0ba9977ccc35a86a
that takes a simple 1024x1024 png file and resizes it to all the required sizes for you. It even gives you a `Contents.json` asset catalog file.

Second, if you're just sending the beta to your friends, you don't really need to go through TestFlight review yet. You can either create a user account in App Store Connect for each of your friends (note: I'd recommending using your own email address `me+friendsname@yourdomain.com` for their accounts so they can't actually log into ASC and see any of your data), or you can create an Adhoc distribution profile for your app and include your friends device UUID's. Then you build your `.ipa` file and send it to them to install. You could even use a new project I've just created: https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/OTAgo and let them install the app over the air, via a web site. Note that project is brand new and thus is still in beta (will change a lot in the coming weeks, but it should be decent enough for your use case).

Comment: Yes I should just sort those issues out anyway. Just being a slacker! Thanks for the links and advice that resizing script looks really useful.